# Plot 3D boolean Array or matrix in Mathematica

Tags: plotting, matrix, list-manipulation

I have been attempting several methods to plot a 3D diagram of a n by n boolean array in *Mathematica* but none of them produced satisfactory result. I want the $3D$ plot to have a cube when `M[i,j,k] == 1` and when `M[i,j,k] == 0` just leaves as blank. Below is the best result I got.

```
L=10
M = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {L, L, L}];
For[k = 1, k <= L, k++,
  For[j = 1, j <= L, j++,
   For[i = 1, i <= L, i++,
    If[M[[i, j, k]] < 0.5,
     M[[i, j, k]] = 1,
     M[[i, j, k]] = 0
     ]]]];
Image3D[M, ImageSize -> 500, Boxed -> True]
```

[image]

The `Image3D` function gives a very fluffy and opaque look on the cubes which I couldn't change!!

Is there someway I can change the opacity and color of the `Image3D` function in this case? Or is there a better way to plot this matrix?

Answer (score 6):

```
L = 10;
```

First of all you could get Booolian array simply as (thx. to @Kuba)

```
RandomInteger[1,{L,L,L}]
```

But if you are interested in thresholding:

```
M = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {L, L, L}];
```

First of all do not binarize procedurally, use functional style, say:

```
bM = M /. x_ -> UnitStep[x - .5];
```

or image processing:

```
bM = ImageData[Binarize[Image3D[bM], .5]];
```

Then if you don't like Image3D - which I think is totally fine, use Graphics3D:

```
Table[Graphics3D[{Hue[RandomReal[]], {Opacity[k], Cuboid[#]} & /@ 
    Position[bM, 1]}], {k, .01, 1, .19}]
```

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[Sphere[#, r] & /@ Position[bM, 1], 
  ViewVertical -> {-1, 0, 0}, Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral", 
  Background -> Black, SphericalRegion -> True]
 , {r, .03, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: @RahulNarain yes thank you

Comment: @Kuba sure I added it. I was just thinking he is interested in thresholding.

Comment: You are probably right :)

Comment: Very useful stuff!! Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
L = 10;
ArrayPlot3D[
 RandomChoice[{0.5, 0.5} -> {0, 1}, {L, L, L}]
 , OpacityFunction -> (0.5 # &)
 , Mesh -> False
 , DataReversed -> {False, True, False}
 , ColorRules -> {1 -> Nest[Lighter, Green, 4]}
 , Boxed -> True
 , Axes -> True
 ]
```

[image]