# 3D Sparse array

Tags: plotting, matrix, list-manipulation, sparse-arrays

Following the 3D matrix representation shown here 
[Vitaliy Kaurov's answer for "Plot 3D boolean Array or matrix in Mathematica"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45628/plot-3d-boolean-array-or-matrix-in-mathematica)

Is it possible to use a `SparseArray` in the same method?

```
M=RandomReal[{0},{10,10,10}];
M[[5,5,5]]=1;
s=SparseArray[M2];


bM=s/.x_->UnitStep[x-.5];
Graphics3D[{Hue[RandomReal[0.96]],{Opacity[0.65],Sphere[#,0.5]}&/@Position[bM,1]}]
```

However, this doesn't plot anything

On a side note what is the size limit of 3D matrices to be manipulated efficiently?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find position of non-zero elements in SparseArray without converting to a dense object](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/125380/how-to-find-position-of-non-zero-elements-in-sparsearray-without-converting-to-a). The problem you are facing is that `Position[bM, 1]` doesn't work when `bM` is a sparse array. The linked question should help you work around this.

Comment: @CarlWoll Perfect!

`bM = s /. x_ -> UnitStep[x - .5];
Graphics3D[{Hue[RandomReal[0.96]], {Opacity[0.65], Sphere[#, 0.5]} & /@
    bM["NonzeroPositions"]}]` works nicely :)